# RTL8812au Driver was idle all night, died this morning

Tags: drivers, usb, realtek, adapter

---------------**Update - Fixed, see below**----------------

New upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. The 16.04 is a new DVD install too. After install, decided to upgrade to 18.04. Quad core ASUS + AMD tower computer. 8GB RAM. Newer 1TB HDD.

Downloaded the 8812au drivers from the manufacturers web site yesterday using my RaLink wifi adapter which worked fine as soon as plugged into a USB port. Then installed the drivers, connected the Realtek USB adapter (RT) and it worked all day. Even worked in tandem with the RaLink adapter. Downloaded and installed my favorite apps and programs. Everything went well.

Then late in the day installed KiCAD CAD software, V4. Discovered an issue with mouse trails and upgraded to V5. Went to bed with it still downloading.

This morning, discovered that the RT wifi adapter wasn't shown and wasn't connected. Checked Network Connections and it showed that it had been connected 11 minutes prior. Rebooted. Network manager still did not show the adapter. This was so long after the KiCad installation would have finished I doubt that that had anything to do with it. It doesn't run in the background either.

Reinstalled the drivers...that went well no errors. Still not shown in Network manager. Rebooted. Still not shown.

Moved the adapter over to my Win7 machine. Hardware discovered, drivers installed, got online. Moved adapter back to Ubuntu machine, not discovered. Tried different USB ports, not discovered. Plugged the RaLink adapter into the same USB port, online in seconds.

So the RaLink adapter works fine, the Realtek adapter drivers only worked for a few hours and died, but the hardware is fine when tested on another machine. Any advice???

```
dkms status
rtl8812au, 4.3.14, 4.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: built
```

Edit: After following the driver delete instructions below:

1) dkms status is NULL

2)

```
`ls -al /usr/src
total 32

    drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 18 13:01 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Apr 20  2016 ..
    drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jun 16 08:17 linux-headers-4.15.0-51
    drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 16 08:17 linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic
    drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jun 17 22:10 linux-headers-4.15.0-52
    drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 17 22:10 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic
    drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun 18 13:01 rtl8812au-4.2.2
    drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun 18 07:10 rtl8812au-4.3.14

3)modinfo 8812au

    filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-52-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko
    version:        v4.3.8_12175.20140902
    author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
    description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
    license:        GPL
    srcversion:     0FE007DE1CB755560C5BB1D
    alias:          usb:v056Ep4007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0411p0242d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2019pAB32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0E66p0023d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2001p3318d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2001p3314d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v04BBp0953d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v7392pA813d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v7392pA812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp0820d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp8822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp0821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp0811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0411p025Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2357p0103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2357p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v20F4p805Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v148Fp9097d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v13B1p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v050Dp1109d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
    depends:        cfg80211
    retpoline:      Y
    name:           8812au
    vermagic:       4.15.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload 
    parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
    parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
    parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
    parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
    parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
    parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
    parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
    parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
    parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
    parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
    parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
    parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
    parm:           rtw_channel:int
    parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
    parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
    parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
    parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
    parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
    parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
    parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
    parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
    parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
    parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
    parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
    parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
    parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
    parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
    parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
    parm:           rtw_low_power:int
    parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
    parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
    parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
    parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
    parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
    parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
    parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
    parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
    parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
    parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
    parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
    parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
    parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable, 2:auto (uint)
    parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
    parm:           rtw_nhm_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
    parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
    parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
    parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
    parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
    parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
    parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
    parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
    parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
    parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
    parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
```

Jun25:

```
lsusb
Bus 009 Device 009: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 009 Device 008: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 275d:0ba6  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

ls -al /usr/src
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jun 18 15:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Apr 20  2016 ..
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jun 16 08:17 linux-headers-4.15.0-51
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 16 08:17 linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jun 17 22:10 linux-headers-4.15.0-52
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jun 17 22:10 linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic
```

The Realtek adapter isn't working right now, but the Ralink adapter is fine so I am switching back and forth between them.

---------------Jun25 after installing new drivers-------------------

```
dkms status
```

rtl8812au, 4.3.14, 4.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

```
modinfo 8812au
```

modinfo: ERROR: Module 8812au not found.

New stuff:

```
modinfo rtl8812au
```

filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-52-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8812au.ko
version:        v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     EDC0561E503CC99CD8C4B3D
alias:          usb:v3823p6249d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v056Ep400Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v056Ep4007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p029Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p025Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0242d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0023d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3318d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3314d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0953d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA813d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0823d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0820d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp9097d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0122d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0115d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p805Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2604p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1109d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           rtl8812au
vermagic:       4.15.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_led_enable:Enable status LED (int)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_dml:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_OffEfuseMask:default open Efuse Mask vaule:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_FileMaskEfuse:default drv Mask Efuse vaule:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)

------------New Stuff 2----------------
locate -b 8812au|grep -i /lib

```
/lib/modules/4.15.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8812au.ko
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.14/4.15.0-52-generic/x86_64/module/rtl8812au.ko
```

------------New Stuff 3 -- **FIXED!!**----------------

Appreciated the help from a forum member and it appears now that I must have missed a period or something as I couldn't get it to work following his instruction.

Anyway, after that failure, took a couple days off, and than today I did another google search and found these instructions in the following link. Followed them closely and viola! It worked, and my new Realtek adapter is working fine now. It's showing 2X download speed over my older RaLink adapter...which is why I bought it.

Here's the link: [[Solved] Realtek 8812au drivers installed](https://www.learningpenguin.net/2018/01/30/install-realtek-rtl8812au-wifi-driver-linux/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95503/discussion-on-question-by-user464356-rtl8812au-driver-was-idle-all-night-died-t).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have really old rtl8812au drivers. The most current that I'm aware of is 5.2.20.2_28373.20180619, and can be obtained at https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au.

Second, you have a "WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!" error, which indicates multiple 8812au drivers installed.

To solve this you have to:

- `dkms remove` all 8812au drivers, all kernels, and `dkms status` should show null

  - `dkms remove rtl8812au/4.3.14 --all`
  - `dkms remove rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg --all`
  - `dkms status` should show null
- manually delete any leftover `8812au.ko` drivers from `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms`

  - `sudo rm /lib/modules/4.15.0-52-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko`
- manually delete any 8812au directories in `/usr/src` for old versions of the driver

  - `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2`
  - `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.3.14`
- `modinfo 8812au` should show null
- download or `git clone` the driver mentioned above
- copy the folder to `/usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.20`, as per the README file

  - `sudo cp -r folder_name /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.20`
- `dkms add/build/install` the new 8812au driver obtained from above, as per the README file
- `dkms status` should show new driver installed on current kernel
- insert dongle into USB port and test connectivity

**Update #1:**

It looks like none of the rtl8812au drivers support your Realtek wireless dongle with device ID of 0bda:a811. However, after a lot of searching, I found one that does at https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.

**First we have to do a little cleanup...**

In `terminal` type `modinfo 8812au` and it should show details of the currently installed 8812au v5.2.20 driver. Then go to the previously downloaded rtl8812au v5.2.20 folder and type `sudo make uninstall`. This should remove the currently installed 8812au driver. To confirm, type `modinfo 8812au` and it should indicate that no such driver exists.

In `terminal` type `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.20`.

**Then we install a different driver...**

Obtain the driver from the source I mentioned earlier. Either get the .zip file, or via `git clone`.

Follow the dkms installation instruction found in the README file, which indicate `sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install`. `dkms status` should now show an installed driver on the current kernel. `modinfo 8812au` should show details of the installed module.

Insert the Realtek wireless dongle, and if it doesn't show up immediately, reboot the computer and recheck.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95100/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-rtl8812au-driver-was-idle-all-night-died-this).